# What exception is thrown if a web service I'm using times out?

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, system.net.webexception

I'm calling a .NET 2.0 web service within my existing .NET 2.0 web service. I would like to know what exception is thrown from the web method if a timeout happens. I have set the web service timeout to some lower value than the default 90 seconds and I want to add business logic if timeout happens.

Is `[System.Net.WebException][1]` the exception I should be looking at?

Answer (score 9):

This kind of depends on which "version" of web services you are using.

Using WCF, you will actually get a [TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx).  You should generally also handle [CommunicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception.aspx) if you are attempting to handle timeouts.  Sometimes I've also seen [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx), although that technically *shouldn't* happen (but it does anyway once in a while).  `FaultException` is a descendant of `CommunicationException` so you don't need to handle it separately, it's just useful to know that it might occur.

In ASMX, you will usually get a wrapped [SoapException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx) for which you need to check the `InnerException` property to see what really went wrong.

Using WSE, you'll see yet another exception, [ResponseProcessingException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.responseprocessingexception.aspx), for which again you must check the `InnerException` for details.

Comment: I'm using .NET 2.0 web services

Comment: @BT: *.NET 2.0* isn't a type of web service, it's a Framework version.  Assuming you mean ASMX web services, see the third paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! i assume that the InnerException is also a type of exceptio, so my question remains there that how i'm going to know that it's timeout exception, i mean what type of inner exception i should be looking at?

Comment: @BT: Judging by some of the (very old) bug reports in our database, the `InnerException` is likely to be an `HttpException` with `HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout` (HTTP 408).  Although there may have been other kinds of timeouts that went unreported.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for a [`TimeoutException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when the time allotted for a process or operation has expired.

Comment: It does not work in case of web service. Catching [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx) will do.